# Java - Generate Random Integers efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, random, integer

I have a list of arrays (array size 5), each array contains integer numbers from 1 to 17 where each integer appears only once in each array. For example the first array in my list is (1, 4, 2, 15, 13), the second array in my list is (2, 5, 9, 13, 7) and so on.

I want to generate a random array and this array should not be equal to one in my list. To be more precise, I do not want to have an array (2, 5, 9, 13, 7) as it is already in my list (the second in my list, see above). Is there any efficient way to solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a `set` of `set`s would work.  Assuming that `[1,2,3,4,5] = [5,4,3,2,1]`. `Set`s in java guarantee that each element placed in them appear only once.

Comment: The assumption is right ([1,2,3,4,5] = [5,4,3,2,1]). So, if I got you right, I have to pack each array in a set and then I'm gonna create a new array and compare it with one of my sets - is that right?

Comment: You would convert your arrays to `set`s and store those `set`s in a single `set`.

Comment: *"Is there any efficient way to solve this?"* Yes

Comment: Thanks to both Andreas for their valuable help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments: Convert the arrays to `set`s and add those to another `set`. i.e:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> storage = new HashSet<>();

public void doSomething() {
     // loop or do something interesting.
     storage.add(getNextGeneratedSet());
}

public Set<Integer> getNextGeneratedSet() {
     Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
     for(int i : getNextRandomInt()) {
         result.add(i);
     }
     return result;
}
```

Two of the nice properties of `set`s are that order doesn't matter and that uniqueness does.  Which both help you immensely in this case; and they do it efficiently.  Java's `hashset` implementation is O(1) on `add` and `contains` -- the two methods you'll use.